# My navbar is transparent but i want to change the toggle background to a colour

Tags: html, css, navigation, toggle, bootstrap-5

The Navbar i have built in Bootstrap 5 is transparent but on the toggle view on mobile the nav links are being lost within the hero image text. I would like to keep the main navigation bar as transparent and alter the background of just the toggle to #F7F5F0 and remove the brand logo from the toggle view. I have tried the first two options below, neither of which are working and now a little stumped as how to fix this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```css
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    background: #F7F5F0;
  }
}

.collapse .navbar-collapse {
  background-color: #F7F5F0;
}

.navbar-brand {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  max-height: 60px;
  max-width: 60px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
}

ul .nav {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navbar {
  align-items: end;
  background: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  --bs-navbar-nav-link-padding-x: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%;
  list-style-type: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  --bs-navbar-toggler-border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 180px;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #252525;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  margin: 15px 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Mothers Spines MS Logo"></a>
      <ul id="nav" class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="active nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link hover-underline-animation" href="index.html">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link hover-underline-animation" href="about.html">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link hover-underline-animation" href="contact.html">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you need to add !important to your CSS background to put it in higher priority than bootstrap:

```
 background-color: #F7F5F0!important;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This should be considered a last resort. CSS selectors can usually be made more specific without this nuclear option, which makes further development more difficult.